# acquia cloud - images in content break, different path local vs cloud/server

Tags: media, acquia-cloud

On my local dev environment, my images are stored in (relative to server root) /sites/default/files/images/

On the server, acquia cloud implements a virtual directory and the end result is that images are stored relative to root in /files/images

In my content nodes, I'm using root-relative paths for my images.  But this means any time I migrate my content between the local environment and the server, all images break.

I don't want to have to take any manual steps to change image paths every time I migrate content (I migrate content "down" from server to lcal periodically so that I am developing against "real" content).

Shouldn't there be some simpler way to configure things so that the root-relative image paths can intelligently choose the correct path based on which environment is being accessed?

Comment: How exactly you embed images in content? And no, usually content is just a piece of, well, content, and cannot change easily. There are ways, of course (look for filters), but people I know would simply link folders to obtain identically - looking folder structure between dev, staging and production. Why won't you do this? Last, but most important: **don't ask us what should be, ask us specific, non-speculative question.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a directory redirect on your local environment's web server so that any request for /files/*  gets redirected to /sites/default/files/*

For example in Apache,  edit the httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName yourservername
  DocumentRoot "pathtoyourdocroot"
  Redirect /files /sites/default/files
</VirtualHost>
```